# Error: select Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, when I try to  run my project I get an error on a configuration page:  Error: Please select an SDK.   I do not know where to go to select the SDK!

Comment: You may wish to capture a screenshot of what you are seeing, upload it somewhere, and link to that image from your question.

Answer (score 2):

From your project:

1.File->Project Structure

2.In Android SDK location select the SDK directory.

If you dont have SDK in your computer. You need to go [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i), and choose 
`GET THE SDK FOR AN EXISTING IDE`, then download SDK for your OS.

Comment: I have the SDK on my computer and my SDK directory list the SDK for my appication as installed. I am thinking about deleting the complete installation of Android Studio and reinstalling.